# VSCode icon is missing in app switcher on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, snapcraft, compiz

After I installed VSCode using the the "Snap Store" on Ubuntu Mate 20.04 (Using compiz).
When I do the app switching with `ALT+TAB` the icon of the VSCode icon is missing.

The original path for the icon is at `/snap/code/43/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png`.
[image]

I encountered this issue only in the app switcher for VSCode.

Other snap apps works as they should.
[image]

The content of `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop`:

```sh
[Desktop Entry]
X-SnapInstanceName=code
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --unity-launch %F
Icon=/snap/code/43/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Code
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;
Actions=new-empty-window;
Keywords=vscode;

[Desktop Action new-empty-window]
Name=New Empty Window
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop /snap/bin/code --force-user-env --no-sandbox --new-window %F
Icon=/snap/code/43/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png
```

Comment: Newer 'code' installs set a desktop file as `/usr/share/applications/code.desktop`. Do `apt install --reinstall code`, move out somewhere (as backup) the current `~/local/share/applications/code.desktop`, logout/back, the non-icon should have disappeared. Start manually *code*, click 'lock to launcher'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install through snap, sometimes the `*.desktop` file does not update correctly.
You should change the `Icon=` path in the following file, which is the one the system uses:

```
/usr/share/applications/code_code.desktop
```

So for instance, I had to change `/usr/share/applications/code_code.desktop` attributes of `[Desktop Entry]` and `[Desktop Action new-empty-window]`, with the correct path in `Icon=`, which I found in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop`

`Icon=/snap/code/85/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png`
instead of
`Icon=/snap/code/64/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png`

I guess you can also do:
`cat /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop > /usr/share/applications/code_code.desktop`

Answer (score 1):

This is VSCode bug #71942 on github. Edit /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop and change the Icon path to /snap/code/43/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png

Comment: it is already the existing path path
> Icon=/snap/code/43/meta/gui/com.visualstudio.code.png